# Working With Version Numbers

Tags: git, github

What is the best way to use version numbers with Git/GitHub?  I understand that when you make a commit, all previous versions are "snapshotted" so they can be retrieved.  But how can you make that coincide with application/assembly version numbers?

For instance, say you have `version: 1.0.0.0` and you commit it.  Then you have `version 1.0.0.1` and commit that.  So on and so forth.

Now it's `version 1.0.0.14` and you want to pull the code from `version 1.0.0.5`.  What's the easiest way to do that with Git/GitHub?

Comment: What "version numbers"? You mean "tags"?

Comment: @pst I mean having Git keep track of my version numbers for later retrieval (I think Greg has the answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to use [*tags*](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-tag.html). Tags are like a pointer to a specific version that never changes. Create a tag like this:

```
git tag -a version-1.0.0.5
```

The above creates a tag at the current commit. (Refer to the documentation for how to create a tag pointing to a previous commit.) Push the tags to Github with:

```
git push origin --tags
```

Comment: And later if you want to get that tag: git checkout version-1.0.0.5

Comment: So `git push origin --tags` will push the current commit **as well as** the tags to GitHub?  Or that'll just push the current tags?

Comment: @Shark: The documentation says for `--tags`: "All refs under refs/tags are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line."

Comment: Worked perfectly, Greg, thanks!  So is tagging the root of versioning with Git?  In other words, is tagging what allows you to correlate point-in-time source?

Comment: @Shark: I would say the "root of versioning" for Git is the *directed acyclic graph* of commits, which means each commit has a fixed commit id and points to one or more parents (see [Git for Computer Scientists](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/)). A tag is basically just a name that points to a specific commit.

Comment: Ah, great explanation.  Sort of like an alias.  I wish I could +10 your answer.  New to the Git world, yet loving every second of it.  How did I live without it??

Comment: @Shark Also might want to give Hg a try -- I like it (and it's sure easier to "train" my team on and get it accepted in a VS/Microsoft shop ;-), but YMMV. They are both great DVCS tools that are based around the same concepts (with slightly different approaches to get there).